# Search a Table for a Lack of Records

Tags: ms-access

Please understand this is not my field. I have inherited an access database from a previous employee.  I have a database which logs training so I have 1 table with employees names trade etc.  I then have a table with all the training each person has had.  What I need to do is search to find the names of employees who have not had a specific type of training logged in the second table.  I would like to enter the training description and then it return a list of employee names who have not had this training.

Can anyone help please
Thanks
Regards
Derek

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful if you post the table design, or at least what you will be joining on.  I created a sample that has 2 tables:

1) Student - Name (PK)

2) Training - Id (PK, Autonumber), Name, Class, Date

Create a relationship between Student.Name, Training.Name, enforce referential integrity.

There is a nice "Find Unmatched Records" query wizard in access that will get you going...  I used it as a base and came up with:

```
SELECT Student.Name
FROM Student 
  LEFT JOIN Training ON Student.[Name] = Training.[Name]
WHERE (((Training.Name) Is Null));
```

From here you can add additional logic in your where clause to whittle it down.

Edit : I missed the part about a specific class - this is probably closer to what you are after:

```
SELECT Student.Name
FROM Student 
where name not in (select name from training where class='your class here')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked "sort of" it shows the ones with a specific type of training so I suppose by definition anyone not on the list does not have it.  I think we can work with this.   Cheers

Comment: Apologies, I missed the specific class part.  I updated my answer to what you originally asked.